# Hosting my website and its database in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I have successfully made a website somehow. Now I am making it live. I know how upload all the pages into the cpanel of my hosting service but I am unable to import my database in cpanel phpmyadmin. I know while working on Xampp and I had the default username for every database i.e 
"localhost, root and "" " 
but I guess now i need to make a phpmyadmin username and password and then put that into each and every page where it requires, is that so.

help me with some tutorial links or something like that

Comment: This is not a place to ask this. You can google it somehow.

Comment: There are lot's of tutorials on Google or something like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two things:

1. First Database Name: It should be: cpanel_database For example: If
   your cpanel username is "pqr", database names can only be
   "pqr_something"
2. Cpanel Databases have specific username and passwords. "root" and "" have no access. Go to Database Wizard of your cPanel and create a user with password. It should now work.